# SpriteKit physics bodies move through each other despite collision bit masks set

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody, skscene, skphysicsworld

I am making a game that uses Doodle Jump like jumping where you can go through platforms if you're moving up but not if you're moving down, except there is a ground platform that is always there. You can't ever get below this ground platform. However, if the player is moving fast enough the player goes through the ground platform like in the picture:

[image]

Even more confusing is that this only happens about 1 in 5 times of doing a jump and only happens to the ground platform, which is identical to the higher platforms. Another thing that is unusual is that if the player is below the ground, it still properly detects hitting enemies as if it were on the ground even though the image is fully below ground, which makes me think the physics body and the image somehow aren't synchronized.

I am using static `SKPhysicsBody`s to represent that platforms & ground and a dynamic `SKPhysicsBody` to represent the player. I have the `platform.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player` for the platforms, and `player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Platforms` for the player. I also have `physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true` for both. Both use rectangles to implement their physics bodies, with the platforms having a thickness of 2.

I've tried everything and nothing seems to be able to fix this. I even tried tacking in checking for this is `didSimulatePhysics()`.

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {
        if self.player.position.y <= 1/7 * size.height {

            player.position.y = 1/7*size.height //+ CGFloat(yScaler) * size.height
            if let body = player.physicsBody {
                if body.velocity.dy < 0 {
                    self.player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`didSimulatePhysics()` properly detects when this happens, yet when I try adjusting player.position.y it doesn't update it at all and remains trapped below the ground!

Any ideas on what's going on here? I'm at wits end. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try setting ‘showPhysics’ to ‘true’ in GameViewControoller.swift, in case your physics bodies are not aligned with their textures.

Comment: How fast can the player sprite move? Is it a normal, platforming type speed or really really fast? Also, when the player goes through the ground, does it always go through by the same amount and then stop in the same place?

Comment: Just tried setting showPhysics to true and that didn't work. As it turns out, the physics body and the image was aligned after all.

Comment: The player moves at a normal speed, nothing crazy fast. When the player goes through the ground, it varies how far he goes. He slows down when he hits the ground and starts slowly floating through the ground

Comment: If you know the ground works most of the time but not all of the time then you know the problem is not with your masks.  There is probably a gap between your 2 platforms that allows the player fall through.

Comment: You say that the player mango through the platform from below, but not from above. How is this done? Is it possible that you are somehow allowing the player to pass through the ground from above (partially) in some situations?

Comment: @SteveIves oh my god... yes that was the issue!!! Before in update() I would check if the player's velocity was > 0 and if so disable collisions. For some reason this velocity would occasionally be a positive value even though no jump was made... Strange. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I'm quite sure the 1 in 5 times thing (or this happening randomly) has something to do with the framerate. The hero is falling, i.e. changing its position too quickly. try logging the relevant x/y position in the update method and you will see how much of a value range is skipped from time to
 time.